# calculation of amount for quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a question, I want merge my table data through date, All information provide in given table

If Aggregation =Quaterly

My table

**Table-1**

```
Amount |   Date      | Aggregation

100    |  2013-01-01 | Quaterly
100    |  2013-02-01 | Quaterly
100    |  2013-03-01 | Quaterly
200    |  2013-04-01 | Quaterly
200    |  2013-05-01 | Quaterly
200    |  2013-06-01 | Quaterly
300    |  2013-07-01 | Quaterly
300    |  2013-07-01 | Quaterly
300    |  2013-09-01 | Quaterly
400    |  2013-10-01 | Quaterly
400    |  2013-11-01 | Quaterly
400    |  2013-12-01 | Quaterly
```

I want result like this

```
Amount |   Date      | Aggregation

300    |  2013-03-01 | Quaterly 
600    |  2013-06-01 | Quaterly 
900    |  2013-09-01 | Quaterly 
1200   |  2013-12-01 | Quaterly
```

Comment: I have no concept for Quarter so i'm able find any solution @NagarajS

Answer (score 0):

Check here its a financial quater + sum

[Checkout here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c751/8)

```
;With Totals as (

    SELECT  SUM(Amount) as Total,
            DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,date),0) as RoundQuarter
    FROM    dbo.MyData AS om
    GROUP BY
            DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,date),0)
)
select
    Total,
    DATEPART(year,RoundQuarter) -
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,RoundQuarter) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as FinancialYear,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,RoundQuarter) = 1 THEN 4
       ELSE DATEPART(quarter,RoundQuarter) - 1 END as FinancialQuarter
from
    Totals
```

Comment: This solution hel me but i have one question if i need quarter last date not first date then what i do? suppose quarter date is 1-1-2013 i want 1-3-2014 @dholakiyaankit

Comment: Customize your selection or put requirement static don't change it

Comment: @dholakiyaankit: How?

Answer (score 0):

If your quarters can change only through calendar (not fiscal) years, you can try this one:

```
SELECT amount, 
       Cast(Cast(mydate / 10 * 10000 + ( mydate%10 ) * 300 + 1 AS VARCHAR) AS 
            DATE) AS 
       MyDate, 
       aggregation 
FROM   (SELECT Sum(amount)                                        AS Amount, 
               Datepart(yyyy, mydate) * 10 + Datepart(qq, mydate) AS MyDate, 
               Max(aggregation)                                   AS Aggregation 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY Datepart(yyyy, mydate) * 10 + Datepart(qq, mydate)) a 
ORDER  BY 2
```

First time you calculate all aggregations in subquery (or use WITH-construction) like in another answer. Date is calculated with year-key, if you don't need results through years, 'datepart(yyyy,MyDate)*10+' can be removed. After that you merge quarters numbers with the certain years. Please do not substitute 'MyDate/10*10000' part to 'MyDate*1000', we need to cut unnecessary numbers to generate correct date format.